# Is cmake appropriate for bare-metal embedded systems?

Tags: embedded, cmake, bare-metal

I've been seeing more embedded developers using cmake as a build configuration tool for their bare-metal (i.e. no operating system) embedded systems. But while cmake is great for projects that will run natively on various host architectures, what value does it add over a Makefile in an embedded system, where there is no operating system and the target processor does not change?

EDIT: What advantages does CMake provide over a simple Makefile in cases where the code is designed specifically for one embedded processor / board, which is running bare-metal (i.e. no operating system, at least not a POSIX one)?

Comment: Two big ones: automatic dependency generation (include files), and out-of-source builds, so that you don't muck up your source directories.

Answer (score 9):

I have used Cmake for cross-compiling to embedded systems: it's a very useful tool if you are cross-compilig as well as for native development. Here are some advantages i appreciate for this:

- It's very easy to use and to program
- Powerful but easy to learn script-language
- Cmake supports two kinds of cross-compiling:

  - Specify compiler(s) and you're done
  - Writing toolchain files which contains settings about your target system, Cpu, Compiler etc. With those you can support many different target systems without chaning anything - just write a new toolchain file with required settings.
- Commandline and GUI available
- Open-Source
- Good documentation
- Supported by many IDE's

There are many tools around, but cmake is perfect if you need an easy to use, but very powerful one.

*Ps. Can you describe your scenario a bit more?*

Comment: I spent several hours searching for how to specify flags to compile my startup code (in an assembly .S file) -- finally stumbled upon the CMAKE_ASM_COMPILE_OBJECT variable which as far as I can tell is not covered in the documentation. Do you use it without an OS on the embedded system, or are you typically running Linux or some other POSIX OS on the embedded side?

Comment: Im currently crosscompiling to the embedded (which has an rtos on it).